# Error in Obj-C : Expected identifier or '('

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make a simple app with a button a score counter and a timer but I'm getting some errors

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface xyzViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;
NSInteger count;
NSInteger seconds;
NSTimer *timer;
}
- (IBAction)buttonPressed  //Expected ';' after method prototype
{
count++
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score \n %i", count]
}
@end
```

If I add ';' I get this instead:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed;
{                        //Expected identifier or '('
count++
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score \n %i", count]
}
@end
```

What I must to do?

Comment: What does `;` mean? (Compiler, this is the end of my line)

Comment: Please take some time to learn Objective-C before going any further. There are plenty of good tutorials or books just on the language. You must understand the basics of the language before you can write iOS/Cocoa apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up `interface` and `implementation`. The interface contains
the (globally visible) instance variables, properties and method *declarations*, i.e.
the prototypes:

```
@interface xyzViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;
    NSInteger count;
    NSInteger seconds;
    NSTimer *timer;
}
- (IBAction)buttonPressed;

@end
```

The method itself goes into the implementation:

```
@implementation xyzViewController

- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    count++;
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score \n %i", count];
}
@end
```

*Remarks:*

- The convention is to start class names with a capital letter: `XyzViewController`.
- Create *properties* for the outlets (if you don't have them already):

  ```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
  ```

  The compiler synthesizes the instance variable `_scoreLabel` automatically, so you don't need it in the interface. And then access the property via

  ```
  self.scoreLabel.text = ....;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Define your interface in the .h iff they are to be public, then create your implementation in the .m.  You can't combine them in the .h

Answer (score 1):

You want semicolons inside the function like so:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
count++;
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score \n %i", count];
}
```

This is the correct syntax to use.

Comment: True, but only a part of the problem. :-)

Comment: True, but this doesn't fix the OP's problem.