# Xcode 5 Expected identifier error wont go away

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed {
  count++;

  scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i", count];
}
```

Following off a beginners ios tutorial. He doesn't get an error. I receive the error just after `-(IBAction)buttonPressed` saying i need to put in a `;` but it doesn't have a `;` and when I do put a `;` in it doesn't do anything!

Comment: What is the exactly error message?

Comment: please show the error message

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE***

This exact same problem was answered [here error-in-obj-c-expected-identifier-or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937601/error-in-obj-c-expected-identifier-or).

It is possible you are doing the something that was wrong by placing the IBAction code in the @interface

[image]

Rather than   @implementation.

[image]

---

**Original Answer**

It is most likely you are getting this because of an error in the code before

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed {
  count++;

  scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i", count];
}
```

An example that would do this is if you are missing a closing bracket "}" on the code just proceeding it.

Example:

[image]

Adding the  closing bracket "}" back corrects the error.

[image]

The error is being directed at the IBAction. But it was code before it that was incorrect.

Yours may be a similar issue of code else where being the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

hey if you make this button action method by nib than correct your method

```
- (IBAction)buttonpressed:(id)sender
```

If you create this button action method programmically than change its return type

```
 - (void)buttonpressed
```

Hope this will work